# How to return values from an associative array in a php class

Tags: php, oop

I'm new to PHP and I'm only just starting to find my way, but I'm having  trouble getting values out of a public associative array using a public function which incorporates a `foreach()` loop. PHP code is encapsulated as a class and embedded within a html file. The html content is being displayed without any problems, but the PHP section is not returning any results.

The code I've been trying to use is shown. I've checked the code through several php validators and there are no syntax errors being returned, but I'm obviously missing something in the code which is preventing

```
<?php
class balances {

    public $custBalances = [
        'Customer 1' => 450,
        'Customer 2' => 900,
        'Customer 3' => 0,
        'Customer 4' => 450
    ];

    public function oustandingBalances() {
        foreach ($custBalances as $key => $value) {
            if ($value == 0)
                continue;
            echo "<p>$key is $value.</P>";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

The php should return results for Customer 1, Customer 2 and Customer 4. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: if you want to access the defined properties inside your class, you should use `foreach ( $this->custBalances as ..` like so

Comment: Michael you said:- `PHP code is encapsulated as a class and embedded within a html file.`. php code inside `.html` extension will not work, you have to save file with `.php` extension.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to access properties of the same class-object inside a function of that class/object you have to use `$this->propertyName` instead of `$propertyName`. Otherwise you are trying to get a property that was declared inside the function and is not member of the object.

```
<?php
class balances {

    public $custBalances = [
        'Customer 1' => 450,
        'Customer 2' => 900,
        'Customer 3' => 0,
        'Customer 4' => 450
    ];

    public function oustandingBalances() {
        foreach ($this->custBalances as $key => $value) {
            if ($value == 0)
                continue;
            echo "<p>$key is $value.</P>";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score -2):

You need to use `$this->custBalances` in your function "oustandingBalances".